# What are the pros and cons of aluminum coils versus copper coils in an electric hvac unit? Why?

Tags: hvac

What Are the pros and cons of aluminum coils versus copper coils in an electric hvac unit?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: Copper is more conductive, while aluminum is cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

1: Aluminum

Pro is cheaper,

Con does not conduct heat transfer as well as other materials like Copper.

2: Copper

Pro - Transfers heat effectively - much better than aluminum.

Con- Costs much more than aluminum..